# Einstein chatbot - Prevent customers from typing a message when a dialog with menu/button is presented

Tags: einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

Einstein chatbot - How to Prevent customers from typing a message when a dialog with menu/button is presented. Disable "Text area for typing" on Einstein Bot, when dialogs with button/ menus provided which requires only menu/button click and not allow customers to type.

I am using Bot over embedded deployment services(Snapins) on Salesforce community.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem currently possible from the bot itself. There's the following [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CZCNQA4) asking for this functionality that you can upvote.

Otherwise, you're left with figuring out a custom way to interact/disable the input.